# Tapestry Extensions (TapX) DateField cannot parse valid DateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, date-format, tapestry, datefield

I'm experiencing an issue with using `tapx-datefield`, more accurately, improved `DateField` component.

My TML:

```
<t:form>
    <t:label for="dateAndTime"/>
    <tx:DateField t:id="dateAndTime" t:format="prop:dateTimeFormat"/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <t:errors/>
</t:form>

<hr/>

<t:if t:test="dateAndTime">
    <p>Date and Time: ${dateAndTime}</p>

    <p:else>
        Nothing :(
    </p:else>
</t:if>
```

My POJO class:

```
public class TestDateTimePage {

    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private Date dateAndTime;

    public DateFormat getDateTimeFormat() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    }
}
```

When I pick the date from the calendar, the `"ss z"` part of the format is ignored:
[image: Error screenshot]

And I know for a fact that that format is just fine:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

> Tue, 25 Mar 2014 12:38:19 GMT

Is this intended behaviour (ignoring seconds, timezone and such) or a bug?
If so, is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've been doing some inspecting of tapx source on GitHub and from what I've seen, it does not have inherent support of parsing seconds:

from [`tapx-datefield Date#parseDate`](https://github.com/hlship/tapx/blob/master/tapx-datefield/src/main/resources/com/howardlewisship/tapx/datefield/jscalendar-1.0/calendar.js) function:

```
...
return new Date(y, m, d, hr, min, 0);
```

while the Date object has the following ctor:

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```